# R: Data tyding when identifiers and variables are in the same column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-cleaning

I came across the following (stylized) data cleaning problem:

```r
df <- data.frame(first_column  = c("country1", "variable1", "variable2","country2", "variable1", "variable2"),
                 second_column = c(NA, "15", "16", NA, "62", "63")
)

df     
#>   first_column second_column
#> 1     country1          <NA>
#> 2    variable1            15
#> 3    variable2            16
#> 4     country2          <NA>
#> 5    variable1            62
#> 6    variable2            63
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I was trying to convert this to a "tidy" (i.e. long or wide format) using `pivot_longer_spec` and `pivot_wider_spec` respectively, but couldn't work it out. There seems to be very little documentation on these functions, and it is difficult for me to find out how to specify the arguments correctly.

Can anyone tell me how to approach this problem, using either these functions or others?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative solution with the zoo package:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(first_column  = c("country1", "variable1", "variable2","country2", "variable1", "variable2"),
             second_column = c(NA, "15", "16", NA, "62", "63"))

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(COUNTRY = ifelse(is.na(second_column), first_column, NA)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(COUNTRY = zoo::na.locf(COUNTRY)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(second_column)) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = first_column, values_from = second_column)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  COUNTRY  variable1 variable2
  <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    
1 country1 15        16       
2 country2 62        63
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Also a very nice solution, without the need for Regex!

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved like so:

1. The "tricky" part is to put the country identifiers in a separate column which I using an ifelse which conditions on `NA` values in the second column (as in the approach by @DPH), `fill` up the country column and `filter` to get rid of the "county rows"
2. After this we can simply `pivot_wider`

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(first_column  = c("country1", "variable1", "variable2","country2", "variable1", "variable2"),
                 second_column = c(NA, "15", "16", NA, "62", "63")
)

df %>% 
  mutate(country = ifelse(is.na(second_column), first_column, NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(country) %>% 
  filter(first_column != country) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "first_column", values_from = "second_column")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   country  variable1 variable2
#>   <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    
#> 1 country1 15        16       
#> 2 country2 62        63
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Abstracting a little bit from this example, this made me realize that the key is indeed to find a regex that can discriminate between the variables and the identifiers.

Comment: I see. So I guess in your case we have real country names. In that case the ifelse proposed by @DPH which extracts the county names by checking for NAs should do the job.

Comment: @stefan I was not aware of the tidyr::fill() - thank you for that!

Comment: @DPH You are welcome. BTW: Your approach using the ifelse is not only simpler but even more robust. Best S.